# Mkdir command resulting in question mark

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, sh

I am trying to create a directory based on input parameter.

Code:

`mkdir a/b/c/d/"$1"` where `$1=1`
But folder is getting created with `?1`.
when I do  `Cd a/b/c/d/1` it says "directory not found"

Comment: 1? is the output

Comment: run your script using `bash -x yourscript.sh` and check the line of `mkdir`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that `$1` doesn't contain what you think it contains. Please [edit] your question to show a complete script that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @kenster $1 contain same value which iam passing from a UI

Answer (score 0):

You first type command mkdir -p a/b/c/d/"$1" then cd  a/b/c/d/"$1" .
and then you will be  result foud.

Comment: Nope dir name is getting changing like 1?